# How to dissect raw data in an email

Tags: email, exchange-2003

There may be an obvious answer to this question, but I have not found it yet.  I have two email messages that were sent to two different people in our company.  One individual did receive the message, the other did not.  I want to try to better understand why.  One way that I can think of to do this is to pick apart the raw email message (we use Exchange 2003) and see if there is a possibility that the problem resides at the senders side rather than our side.

What techniques are typically use to dissect email messages and/or verify their validity.  Also, what can be done on the Exchange side to understand what may have happened to undelivered email messages.  I have asked our local exchange administrator, and he can't answer the question for me, so I'm looking to the community for help -- Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Exchange's message tracking feature to see exactly what path the incoming messages took; that's where I'd start. There's a decent tutorial [here](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Exchange-2003-Message-Tracking-Logging.html). Note that this is something your Exchange admin will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think it's possible do dissect an email message that never arrived :)

1) You should eventually receive an NDR at the sender indicating why a message failed.

2) Enable Message Tracking and you'll get a log of all the messages through the server.  Here's a little [walk-through](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Exchange-2003-Message-Tracking-Logging.html) .

3) Enable logging in the SMTP service (if the messages originated outside of the server).

4) Check your firewall logs, especially if they do any sort of mail filtering (many do).